# Unable to import project from remote git/stash repository to Business-Central

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie-workbench

I am running jbpm 7.16 on jboss eap7.1. I am trying to import the projects from my stash/git repository in business central but getting below error -" There are no projects available to import. Check the repository URL and authentication options."

I am using repo url as https://:8443/myFolder/demo.git" and also providing correct username and password. Even i am not getting any error in logs.

Answer (score 0):

there can be many reasons,

1. your project structure is not as expected by Business-Central
2. Broken pom.xml
3. authentication issue (you are saying its correct)
   4.Kjar archetype for your project

- Please make sure to have your project as kjar project. You can modify the pom.xml.
- Also Make sure that your project folder has its separate directory inside your stash repository. e.g. If you have repository "sample" and project is hello-world then something like below would work

  e.g. go to you your directory
  $ pwd
  ->/Desktop/drools/sample

  Now list down
  $ ls
  -> hello-world

  Now ls hello-world and it should like below,
  $ ls hello-world
  <-- list of of project structure -->
  package-names-white-list project.imports
  pom.xml                  src

Comment: I think your answer is missing some important formatting. Also, can you explain or do you have a link to expand on your first point: "expected by Business-Central". I'll go looking for information on kjar projects because this is the first I have ever read this (I haven't finished the manual)